# Saving file on linux with FileStream of node js

Tags: linux, node.js, meteor

I wan't to save pdf file on meteor server using NodeJs FileStream:

```
var fs = Npm.require('fs');
var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(fileName);
pdf.create(html).toStream(function(err, stream) {
  stream.pipe(writeStream);
});
```

There is no problem when I run code locally on Windows but after mup deploy of app to DigitalOcean server with Ubuntu it crashes my app.

I checked directory with ls -l and meteoruser is owner of directory I want to save file in, yet still it crashes my app.

Why is it crashing? Is there a way of checking what is the problem?

**Edit:**

I found that error I get is ENOENT.

Before piping stream I've tried to write some data to stream and it was success, so the problem must be:

stream.pipe(writeStream);

That gives ENOENT and crashes the server.

Comment: When creating the write stream listen to the `error` event. And also log `err` in the `toStream` callback.

Comment: what path are you using? is it an absolute path?

Comment: I'm giving path like "/opt/directory_to_save" which exists.

Comment: I found that the error messege is ENOENT, but directory exists, as I wrote earlier.

Comment: @RafałPraczyk I solved mup problems by using /tmp/ path it seems to work maybe give it a try